# ruby no method error for customer class... very basic

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and this does not make any sense to me...

```
require './stack.rb'

class Queue

  def initialize
    @in_stack = new Stack
    @out_stack = new Stack
  end

  def enqueue(element)
    @in_stack.push(element)
  end

  def dequeue
    if @out_stack.size == 0
      until @in_stack.size == 0
        @out_stack.push(in_stack.pop)
      end
    end
    @out_stack.pop
  end

end


# test
a_queue = new Queue
```

The last line causes an error: queue.rb:27:in `<main>': undefined method`new' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Isn't this the proper way to initialize a custom class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. The proper way is `Queue.new`. Your code means that you have an implicit receiver (which is `<main>`), and call `new` with the argument `Queue`. To fully spell-out:

```
<main>.new(Queue)
```

This does not make sense to me. What the heck.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to initialize an instance of an object is

```
Class.new
```

not

```
new Class
```

You need to change

```
@in_stack = new Stack
@out_stack = new Stack
```

into

```
@in_stack = Stack.new
@out_stack = Stack.new
```

and

```
a_queue = new Queue
```

into

```
a_queue = Queue.new
```

You may also want to read some Basic introduction to Ruby to learn more about its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to create a new Object of any class in ruby is

```
object = Classname.new()
```

But due to flexibility of ruby you can avoid the parenthesis of any method
and `new()` is actually method we are calling on class so

```
object = Classname.new
```

Here is the corrected code

```
require './stack.rb'

class Queue
  def initialize
    @in_stack = Stack.new
    @out_stack = Stack.new
  end

  def enqueue(element)
    @in_stack.push(element)
  end

  def dequeue
    if @out_stack.size == 0
      until @in_stack.size == 0
        @out_stack.push(in_stack.pop)
      end
    end
    @out_stack.pop
  end
end

# test
a_queue = Queue.new
```